# Qt external library duplicate symbols linking error

Tags: c++, qt

This is my first question on here so please bear with.

I need to add an external library to my qt project in the form of a header file and .so file. If I include the header file (figure.h) only in main.cpp the program compiles and works as intended. If I include the header file only in scene.cpp the program again compiles. However when I go to add the header file to scene.h the compiler states that there are duplicate symbols, even though the header file hasn't been included anywhere else in the project. Is there anyone that could help out? This has had me stumped for a while.

.pro file:

```
    QT       += core gui widgets

    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

    TARGET = moebinv-gui
    TEMPLATE = app

    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include $$PWD/include
    DEPENDPATH += /usr/local/include $$PWD/include

    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -v

    unix: LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lginac -lcycle -lfigure

    SOURCES += \
            src/main.cpp \
            src/mainwindow.cpp \
            src/scene.cpp

    HEADERS += \
            include/mainwindow.h \
            include/scene.h
```

scene.h:

```
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <figure.h>

class graphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    MoebInv::figure *f;

};

#endif // SCENE_H
```

figure.h:

```
// The library for ensembles of interrelated cycles in non-Euclidean geometry
//
//  Copyright (C) 2014-2018 Vladimir V. Kisil <kisilv@maths.leeds.ac.uk>
//
//  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
//  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
//  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
//  (at your option) any later version.
//
//  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
//  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
//  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
//  GNU General Public License for more details.
//
//  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
//  along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

#ifndef ____figure__
#define ____figure__

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include "cycle.h"

namespace MoebInv {
using namespace std;
using namespace GiNaC;
#define REAL_LINE_GEN -1
#define INFINITY_GEN -2
#define GHOST_GEN -3
using PEVAL = std::function<ex(const ex &, const ex &)>;

using PCR = std::function<ex(const ex &, const ex &, const ex &)>;
class cycle_data : public basic
{
GINAC_DECLARE_REGISTERED_CLASS(cycle_data, basic)
protected:
    ex k,
    l,
    m;

public:
    cycle_data(const ex & C);
    cycle_data(const ex & k1, const ex l1, const ex &m1, bool normalize=false);
    ex get_cycle(const ex & metr) const;
    inline size_t nops() const { return 3; }
    ex op(size_t i) const;
    ex & let_op(size_t i);
    inline ex get_k() const { return k; }
    inline ex get_l() const { return l; }
    inline ex get_l(size_t i) const { return l.op(0).op(i); }
    inline ex get_m() const { return m;}
    inline long unsigned int get_dim() const { return l.op(0).nops(); }
    void do_print(const print_dflt & con, unsigned level) const;
    void archive(archive_node &n) const;
    inline ex normalize() const {return cycle_data(k,l,m,true);}
    ex num_normalize() const;
    void read_archive(const archive_node &n, lst &sym_lst);
    bool is_equal(const basic & other, bool projectively) const;
    bool is_almost_equal(const basic & other, bool projectively) const;
    cycle_data subs(const ex & e, unsigned options=0) const;
    ex subs(const exmap & em, unsigned options=0) const;
    inline bool has(const ex & x) const { return (k.has(x) ||  l.has(x) ||  m.has(x)); }

protected:
    return_type_t return_type_tinfo() const;
};
GINAC_DECLARE_UNARCHIVER(cycle_data);

class cycle_relation;

class cycle_node : public basic
{
GINAC_DECLARE_REGISTERED_CLASS(cycle_node, basic)
protected:
    lst cycles; // List of cycle data entries
    int generation;
    lst children; // List of keys to cycle_nodes
    lst parents; // List of cycle_relations or a list containing a single subfigure
    string custom_asy; // Custom string for Asymptote

public:
    cycle_node(const ex & C, int g=0);
    cycle_node(const ex & C, int g, const lst & par);
    cycle_node(const ex & C, int g, const lst & par, const lst & chil);
    cycle_node(const ex & C, int g, const lst & par, const lst & chil, string ca);
    cycle_node subs(const ex & e, unsigned options=0) const;
    ex subs(const exmap & m, unsigned options=0) const;

protected:
    inline void add_child(const ex & c) {children.append(c);}

    inline ex get_cycles() const {return cycles;}

    ex get_cycle(const ex & metr) const;
    inline ex get_cycle_data(int i) const {return cycles.op(i);}

    inline int get_generation() const {return generation;}

    inline lst get_children() const {return children;}

    void set_cycles(const ex & C);

    void append_cycle(const ex & C);
    void append_cycle(const ex & k, const ex & l, const ex & m);

    lst get_parents() const;

    lst get_parent_keys() const ;

    void remove_child(const ex & c);

    inline void set_asy_opt(const string opt)  {custom_asy=opt;}

    inline size_t nops() const { return cycles.nops()+children.nops()+parents.nops(); }
    ex op(size_t i) const;
    ex & let_op(size_t i);
    void do_print(const print_dflt & con, unsigned level) const;
    void do_print_tree(const print_tree & con, unsigned level) const;
protected:
    return_type_t return_type_tinfo() const;
    void archive(archive_node &n) const;
    void read_archive(const archive_node &n, lst &sym_lst);

friend class cycle_relation;
friend class figure;
};
GINAC_DECLARE_UNARCHIVER(cycle_node);

class cycle_relation : public basic
{
    GINAC_DECLARE_REGISTERED_CLASS(cycle_relation, basic)
protected:
    ex parkey; // A key to a parent cycle_node in figure
    PCR rel; // A pointer to function which produces the relation
    ex parameter; // The value, which is supplied to rel() as the third parameter
    bool use_cycle_metric; // If true uses the cycle space metric, otherwise the point space metric
public:
    cycle_relation(const ex & key, PCR rel, bool cm=true, const ex & p=0);
    inline ex get_parkey() const {return parkey;}
    inline PCR get_PCR() const {return rel;}
    inline ex get_parameter() const {return parameter;}
    inline bool cycle_metric_inuse() const {return use_cycle_metric;}
    inline ex subs(const exmap & em, unsigned options=0) const
    {return cycle_relation(parkey, rel, use_cycle_metric, parameter.subs(em,options));}

protected:
    ex rel_to_parent(const cycle_data & C1, const ex & pmetric, const ex & cmetric,
                     const exhashmap<cycle_node> & N) const;
    return_type_t return_type_tinfo() const;
    void do_print(const print_dflt & con, unsigned level) const;
    void do_print_tree(const print_tree & con, unsigned level) const;

    void archive(archive_node &n) const;
    void read_archive(const archive_node &n, lst &sym_lst);

    inline size_t nops() const { return 2; }
    ex op(size_t i) const;
    ex & let_op(size_t i);

friend class cycle_node;
friend class figure;
};
GINAC_DECLARE_UNARCHIVER(cycle_relation);

ex cycle_orthogonal(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0);
ex cycle_f_orthogonal(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0);
ex check_tangent(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0);
ex cycle_different(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0);
ex cycle_adifferent(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0);
ex product_sign(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=1);
ex coefficients_are_real(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=1);

ex cycle_tangent(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0);
ex cycle_tangent_i(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0);
ex cycle_tangent_o(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0);
ex cycle_angle(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr);
ex steiner_power(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr);
ex cycle_cross_t_distance(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr);
ex cycle_moebius(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr);
ex cycle_sl2(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr);
ex power_is(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=1);
inline ex sq_t_distance_is(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=1)
 {return power_is(C1,C2,1);}
inline ex sq_cross_t_distance_is(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=-1)
 {return power_is(C1,C2,-1);}
ex angle_is(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0);
inline cycle_relation is_orthogonal(const ex & key, bool cm=true)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, cycle_orthogonal, cm);}
inline cycle_relation is_f_orthogonal(const ex & key, bool cm=true)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, cycle_f_orthogonal, cm);}
inline cycle_relation is_different(const ex & key, bool cm=true)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, cycle_different, cm);}
inline cycle_relation is_adifferent(const ex & key, bool cm=true)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, cycle_adifferent, cm);}
inline cycle_relation is_real_cycle(const ex & key, bool cm=false, const ex & pr=1)
 {return cycle_relation(key, product_sign, cm, pr);}
inline cycle_relation product_nonpositive(const ex & key, bool cm=true, const ex & pr=1)
 {return cycle_relation(key, product_sign, cm, pr);}
inline cycle_relation only_reals(const ex & key, bool cm=true, const ex & pr=0)
 {return cycle_relation(key, coefficients_are_real, cm, pr);}
inline cycle_relation is_tangent(const ex & key, bool cm=true)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, cycle_tangent, cm);}
inline cycle_relation is_tangent_i(const ex & key, bool cm=true)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, cycle_tangent_i, cm);}
inline cycle_relation is_tangent_o(const ex & key, bool cm=true)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, cycle_tangent_o, cm);}
inline cycle_relation make_angle(const ex & key, bool cm=true, const ex & angle=0)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, cycle_angle, cm, angle);}
inline cycle_relation cycle_power(const ex & key, bool cm=true, const ex & cpower=0)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, steiner_power, cm, cpower);}
inline cycle_relation tangential_distance(const ex & key, bool cm=true, const ex & distance=0)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, steiner_power, cm, pow(distance,2));}
inline cycle_relation cross_t_distance(const ex & key, bool cm=true, const ex & distance=0)
                    {return cycle_relation(key, cycle_cross_t_distance, cm, distance);}
inline cycle_relation moebius_transform(const ex & key, bool cm=true,
                                        const ex & matrix=lst{numeric(1),0,0,numeric(1)})
                    {return cycle_relation(key, cycle_moebius, cm, matrix);}
 cycle_relation sl2_transform(const ex & key, bool cm=true,
                              const ex & matrix=lst{numeric(1),0,0,numeric(1)});

ex metric_e = clifford_unit(varidx(symbol("i"), 2), indexed(diag_matrix(lst{-1,-1}), sy_symm(),
                                                            varidx(symbol("j"), 2), varidx(symbol("k"), 2)));
ex metric_p = clifford_unit(varidx(symbol("i"), 2), indexed(diag_matrix(lst{-1,0}), sy_symm(),
                                                            varidx(symbol("j"), 2), varidx(symbol("k"), 2)));
ex metric_h = clifford_unit(varidx(symbol("i"), 2), indexed(diag_matrix(lst{-1,1}), sy_symm(),
                                                            varidx(symbol("j"), 2), varidx(symbol("k"), 2)));
inline ex cycle_orthogonal_e(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0) {
    return lst{(ex)lst{ex_to<cycle>(C1).is_orthogonal(ex_to<cycle>(C2), metric_e)}};}

inline ex cycle_orthogonal_p(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0) {
    return lst{(ex)lst{ex_to<cycle>(C1).is_orthogonal(ex_to<cycle>(C2), metric_p)}};}

inline ex cycle_orthogonal_h(const ex & C1, const ex & C2, const ex & pr=0) {
    return lst{(ex)lst{ex_to<cycle>(C1).is_orthogonal(ex_to<cycle>(C2), metric_h)}};}
using asy_style=std::function<string(const ex &, const ex &, lst &)>;
//typedef string (*asy_style)(const ex &, const ex &, lst &);
inline string no_color(const ex & label, const ex & C, lst & color) {color=lst{0,0,0}; return "";}
string asy_cycle_color(const ex & label, const ex & C, lst & color);
asy_style default_asy=asy_cycle_color;

using label_string=std::function<string(const ex &, const ex &, const string)>;
//typedef string (*label_string)(const ex &, const ex &, const string);
string label_pos(const ex & label, const ex & C, const string draw_str);
inline string no_label(const ex & label, const ex & C, const string draw_str) {return "";}
//label_string default_label=*no_label;
label_string default_label=label_pos;

class figure : public basic
{
GINAC_DECLARE_REGISTERED_CLASS(figure, basic)

protected:
 ex real_line, // the key for the real line
      infinity; // the key for cycle at infinity
    ex point_metric; // The metric of the point space encoded as a clifford_unit object
    ex cycle_metric; // The metric of the cycle space encoded as a clifford_unit object
    exhashmap<cycle_node> nodes; // List of cycle_node, exhashmap<cycle_node> object
    bool float_evaluation=false;
    ex k, m; // realsymbols for symbolic calculations
    lst l;
protected:
    ex update_cycle_node(const ex & key, const lst & eq_cond=lst{},
                           const lst & neq_cond=lst{}, lst res=lst{}, size_t level=0);
    void set_cycle(const ex & key, const ex & C);
    ex evaluate_cycle(const ex & symbolic, const lst & cond) const;

public:
    figure(const ex & Mp, const ex & Mc=0);
    void set_metric(const ex & Mp, const ex & Mc=0);
    figure(const ex & Mp, const ex & Mc, const exhashmap<cycle_node> & N);
    void reset_figure();
    ex add_point(const ex & x, string name, string TeXname="");
    ex add_point(const ex & x, const ex & key);
    ex add_cycle(const ex & C, string name, string TeXname="");
    ex add_cycle(const ex & C, const ex & key);
    ex add_cycle_rel(const lst & rel, string name, string TeXname="");
    ex add_cycle_rel(const lst & rel, const ex & key);
    ex add_cycle_rel(const ex & rel, string name, string TeXname="");
    ex add_cycle_rel(const ex & rel, const ex & key);
    ex add_subfigure(const ex & F, const lst & L, string name, string TeXname="");
    ex add_subfigure(const ex & F, const lst & L, const ex & key);
    void move_point(const ex & key, const ex & x);
    void move_cycle(const ex & key, const ex & C);
    void remove_cycle_node(const ex & key);
    ex get_cycle_label(string name) const;
    ex get_all_keys(const int mingen = GHOST_GEN+1, const int maxgen = GHOST_GEN) const;
    ex check_rel(const ex & key1, const ex & key2, PCR rel, bool use_cycle_metric=true,
                 const ex & parameter=0, bool corresponds=true) const;
    ex measure(const ex & key1, const ex & key2, PCR rel, bool use_cycle_metric=true,
               const ex & parameter=0, bool corresponds=true) const;
    inline ex get_point_metric() const { return point_metric; }
    inline ex get_cycle_metric() const { return cycle_metric; }
    inline ex get_dim() const { return ex_to<varidx>(point_metric.op(1)).get_dim(); }
    inline ex get_cycle(const ex & k, bool use_point_metric=true) const {
        return get_cycle(k,use_point_metric?point_metric:cycle_metric);}
    ex get_cycle(const ex & k, const ex & metric) const;
    inline ex get_generation(const ex & k) const {
        return ex_to<cycle_node>(get_cycle_node(k)).get_generation();}
    ex apply(PEVAL func, bool use_cycle_metric=true, const ex & param = 0) const;
    void asy_draw(ostream & ost =std::cout, ostream & err=std::cerr, const string picture="",
                  const ex & xmin = -5, const ex & xmax = 5,
                  const ex & ymin = -5, const ex & ymax = 5,
                  asy_style style=default_asy, label_string lstring=default_label,
                  bool with_realline=true, bool with_header=true,
                  int points_per_arc = 0, const string imaginary_options="rgb(0,.9,0)+4pt",
                  bool with_labels=true) const;
    void asy_write(int size=300, const ex & xmin = -5, const ex & xmax = 5,
                   const ex & ymin = -5, const ex & ymax = 5,
                   string name="figure-view-tmp", string format="",
                   asy_style style=default_asy, label_string lstring=default_label,
                   bool with_realline=true, bool with_header=true,
                   int points_per_arc=0, const string imaginary_options="rgb(0,.9,0)+4pt",
                   bool rm_asy_file=true, bool with_labels=true) const;
    void asy_animate(const ex & val,
                     int size=300, const ex & xmin = -5, const ex & xmax = 5,
                     const ex & ymin = -5, const ex & ymax = 5,
                     string name="figure-animatecf-tmp", string format="pdf",
                     asy_style style=default_asy, label_string lstring=default_label,
                     bool with_realline=true, bool with_header=true,
                     int points_per_arc = 0, const string imaginary_options="rgb(0,.9,0)+4pt",
                     const string values_position="bl", bool rm_asy_file=true,
                     bool with_labels=true) const;
    inline figure freeze() const {setflag(status_flags::expanded); return *this;}
    inline figure unfreeze() const {clearflag(status_flags::expanded); return *this;}
    inline figure set_float_eval() {float_evaluation=true; return *this;}
    inline figure set_exact_eval() {float_evaluation=false; return *this;}
    inline void set_asy_style(const ex & key, string opt) {nodes[key].set_asy_opt(opt);}
    void arrangement_write(string name, int first_gen=0) const;
    void save(const char* file_name, const char* fig_name="myfig") const;
    figure(const char* file_name, string fig_name="myfig");
        inline exhashmap<cycle_node> get_nodes() const {return nodes;}

        inline size_t nops() const {return 4+nodes.size();}
        ex op(size_t i) const;
        //ex & let_op(size_t i);
        ex evalf(int level=0) const;
        figure subs(const ex & e, unsigned options=0) const;
        ex subs(const exmap & m, unsigned options=0) const;
        void archive(archive_node &n) const;
        void read_archive(const archive_node &n, lst &sym_lst);
        bool info(unsigned inf) const;

    inline ex get_cycle_node(const ex & k) const {return nodes.find(k)->second;}
    inline ex get_real_line() const {return real_line;}
    inline ex get_infinity() const {return infinity;}
protected:
    void do_print(const print_dflt & con, unsigned level) const;
    return_type_t return_type_tinfo() const;

    void update_node_lst(const ex & inlist);
    figure update_cycles();
};
GINAC_DECLARE_UNARCHIVER(figure);
class subfigure : public basic
{
    GINAC_DECLARE_REGISTERED_CLASS(subfigure, basic)
protected:
    ex subf; // A figure to be inserted
    lst parlist; // A list of key to a parent cycle_node in figure
public:
    subfigure(const ex & F, const ex & L);
    inline ex subs(const exmap & em, unsigned options=0) const;
protected:
    inline ex get_parlist() const {return parlist;}
    inline ex get_subf() const {return subf;}
    return_type_t return_type_tinfo() const;
    void do_print(const print_dflt & con, unsigned level) const;
    void do_print_tree(const print_tree & con, unsigned level) const;

    void archive(archive_node &n) const;
    void read_archive(const archive_node &n, lst &sym_lst);

friend class cycle_node;
friend class figure;
};
GINAC_DECLARE_UNARCHIVER(subfigure);

    void show_asy_on();
    void show_asy_off();
ex midpoint_constructor();
ex unique_cycle(const ex & L);
void figure_debug_on();
void figure_debug_off();
bool figure_ask_debug_status();
ex evaluation_assist = lst{pow(cos(wild(0)),2)==1-pow(sin(wild(0)),2),
        pow(cosh(wild(1)),2)==1+pow(sinh(wild(1)),2)};
} // namespace MoebInv
#endif /* defined(____figure__) */
```

compiler error:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv11default_asyE in:
    main.o
    mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv17evaluation_assistE in:
    main.o
    mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_pE in:
    main.o
    mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv13default_labelE in:
    main.o
    mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_hE in:
    main.o
    mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_eE in:
    main.o
    mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv11default_asyE in:
    main.o
    scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv17evaluation_assistE in:
    main.o
    scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_pE in:
    main.o
    scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv13default_labelE in:
    main.o
    scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_hE in:
    main.o
    scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_eE in:
    main.o
    scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv11default_asyE in:
    main.o
    moc_mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv17evaluation_assistE in:
    main.o
    moc_mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_pE in:
    main.o
    moc_mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv13default_labelE in:
    main.o
    moc_mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_hE in:
    main.o
    moc_mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_eE in:
    main.o
    moc_mainwindow.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv11default_asyE in:
    main.o
    moc_scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv17evaluation_assistE in:
    main.o
    moc_scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_pE in:
    main.o
    moc_scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv13default_labelE in:
    main.o
    moc_scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_hE in:
    main.o
    moc_scene.o
duplicate symbol __ZN7MoebInv8metric_eE in:
    main.o
    moc_scene.o
ld: 24 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [moebinv-gui.app/Contents/MacOS/moebinv-gui] Error 1
12:08:20: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project moebinv-gui (kit: Desktop Qt 5.11.1 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Comment: looks like MoebInv isn't declared correctly in its header files, difficult to tell without seeing the relevant headers, please post a [mcve]

Comment: thanks, I'll edit my answer now. So would this be a problem with the library itself?

Comment: probably is yes

Comment: it's a fairly large file, but hopefully that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define global variables in a header file. For example you have:

```
asy_style default_asy=asy_cycle_color;
```

You either have to declare the variable as `extern` in the header:

```
extern asy_style default_asy;
```

Then define it in one cpp file:

```
asy_style default_asy=asy_cycle_color;
```

Or if the global is actually a constant then you can define it in the header:

```
const asy_style default_asy=asy_cycle_color;
```